# Cannot save animation: no writers available

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Trying to save a gif on Jupyter but keep getting the error message:

```
ValueError: Cannot save animation: no writers are available. Please install mencoder or ffmpeg to save animations.
```

I have tried to install ffmpeg but this hasn't cleared my error message.

This is the code I have written.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.use('Agg')
anim.save('animation.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps = 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming imagemagick was installed correctly, it's possible you simply need to point the `rcParam` `animation.convert_path` to the convert executable, i.e.

```py
rcParam['animation.convert_path'] = '/usr/bin/convert'
```

Note that this must be set **prior** to trying to save the animation. In order to make the change permanent you can modify the matplotlibrc file, the path to which can be retrieved via

```py
matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()
```

you would simply need to append

```
animation.convert_path: /usr/bin/convert
```

Some other answers you may find useful: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46717747/10659910) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35449039/10659910)

Comment: @Emm Can you edit the question to return your current code?